# gamblers fortune expectation[ith game winnings] = 0. Why?

Tags: martingales, expected-value

I couldn't understand the expression below for the problem,

*consider a gambler who plays a sequence of fair games. Let $X_i$ be the amount the gambler wins on the $i^{th}$ game ($X_i$ is negative if the gambler loses), and let $Z_i$ be the gambler's total winnings at the end of the $i^{th}$ game. Because each game is fair,*

> $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$

and $\mathbb{E}[Z_{i+1}|X_1, X_2, ..., X_i] = Z_i + \mathbb{E}[X_{i+1}] =Z_i$

Why is $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$. Even with *fair/unbiased* coin tosses the expectation of heads is 1/2?

Comment: $\mathbb E[X_i]=0$ by assumption...the fact that there is some other variable that has a non-zero expectation doesn't seem relevant.  If you want to use the coin toss as an example, make a fair game out of it by saying you win $1$ if it comes up $H$ and you lose $1$ if it comes up $T$.  The expectation of that is $0$.

Comment: To your other question, knowing $X_1,\cdots, X_{i}$ tells us $Z_i$ but, assuming that all the games are independent, they tell us nothing about the outcome of $X_{i+1}$.  Thus, starting from $Z_i$ you expect the next round to return $0$, so the expected value stays the same.

Comment: You mixed the amount of money the player wins ( a loss is considered as a negative win) with the fraction of the number of heads to the total number of tosses. If the coin shows head in exactly the half of the tosses, the player won exactly amount $0$.

Comment: Somewhat sloppy formulated does $E(X)=0$ mean that the average outcome is that the player does not win or lose anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in ***gamble*** we win (+1) or lose(-1) the expectation  = 1(1/2) + (-1)(1/2) = 0 wheras 
in *coin toss* we lose(0) and win(1), the expectation = 1(1/2) + 0(1/2) = (1/2).